# Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Can't determine Firebase Database URL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When trying to deploy firebase functions, I get the following error.

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me 4 hours to figure this out

Go to your firebase console, and setup/choose your database. You need to make a choice between Realtime and Firestore (Realtime is better in my opinion)